# React Auto Increment counter

Tags: reactjs, state, settimeout, setstate

I replicated this code entirely from a Youtube React tutorial I was following. But the result they got and what i got are entirely different.

```
 class Contact extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { counter: 0 };
        }
        increment() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState((prev,props)=>({ counter: prev.counter + 1 }));
            }, 3000);
        }
        render() {
            this.increment();
            return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
                    </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Contact;
```

result intended: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 .....

Result obtained: 2 4 6 8 12 18 26 34 42 50 56 66 ....

Comment: You call increment() on every render, refer to React tutorial, you would like to use a lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `increment()` inside `render()` so that the interval function is initialized over and over again resulting in unpredictable behaviour.

You need to guarantee, the interval is only initialized once. Therefor you can use the lifecycle hook [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) which is executed once the component is mounted. With intervals and timeouts you should also make sure to clear them at unmount. [`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) is the tool for this task.

Following a working solution:

```
class Contact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
    this.interval = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1,
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.count}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Really thankful for your time. I just figured out the <React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode> tag in Index.js[which unfortunately wasn't attached to my question ] was causing the problem.
do you know why this happened?

Comment: StrictMode helps with Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles, may be that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

**im using react function component** . when im  trying this automatic counter i will used both setinterval and settimeout method but after i found this solution . if anyone give me feedback about this

```html
export default function App() {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function incCounter() {
    console.log("callled");
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }
 
  setTimeout(incCounter, 1000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```